# Elman Network - Negative and above 1 calculation values

Tags: neural-network, encog

I normliezed the data but still, get negative and above 1 values when calculate new data with encog Elman pattern.

Even when run the ElmanXOR sample as is:

layers:     1 input, 5 hidden, 1 output
activation: ActivationSigmoid
training:   LevenbergMarquardtTraining: 
            a. Greedy 
            b. HybridStrategy -> NeuralSimulatedAnnealing

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Encog's Sigmoid Activation function, you should only get output values between 0 and 1 as this is all the output function is capable of (are you sure your output node is not using a Linear activation function?).  It should not be possible to get values above 1 or below -1.

[image: Sigmoid Activation Function]
<sub>(source: [saedsayad.com](http://www.saedsayad.com/images/ANN_Sigmoid.png))</sub>

I'm wondering if your data is not normalized correctly (can you upload a sample of your normalized data?).

When you normalized, I'm assuming you did something like this:

```
        var analyst = new EncogAnalyst();  
        var wizard = new AnalystWizard(analyst);  
        wizard.Wizard(DataFile, true, AnalystFileFormat.DecpntComma);
```

This will normalize your data between -1 and 1.  I think you should try adding this code to normalize everything to between 0 and 1.

```
            foreach (AnalystField field in analyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields)  
            {  
                field.NormalizedHigh = 1.0;  
                field.NormalizedLow = 0.0;  
            }
```

Alternatively, you could try a different activation function, like HyperbolicTangent, as this outputs between -1 and 1.

Comment: Ya, i know, that's the reason it's strange for me.
i even run the original sample of encog from GitHub - ElmanXOR

https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/master/ConsoleExamples/Examples/ElmanNetwork/ElmanExample.cs

and add a compute loop:

foreach (IMLDataPair pair in trainingSet)
{
                IMLData output = elmanNetwork.Compute(pair.Input);
                Console.WriteLine("input: {0}  origOutput: {1}   prediction: {2}", pair.Input[0], pair.Ideal[0], output[0]);
}

Comment: Hi Greg, did you see it? is it making sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
Neural Network Results:
input: 1 ,ideal=0  actual: 0.625124775182661
input: 0 ,ideal=1  actual: -0.476592365362806
input: 1 ,ideal=0  actual: -0.0206919867584277
input: 0 ,ideal=0  actual: 1.35539859989167
input: 0 ,ideal=0  actual: -0.387613018442168
input: 0 ,ideal=0  actual: -0.819489650390268
input: 0 ,ideal=1  actual: 1.2046874965753
input: 1 ,ideal=1  actual: 0.870695301738905
input: 1 ,ideal=1  actual: 0.159201074403962
input: 1 ,ideal=1  actual: 0.884482632556325
```